# Hay algun archivo de cabecera (.h) para C/C++ de Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

En Windows existe un archivo de cabecera ("windows.h") que contiene funciones para la programación en C/C++ en este sistema operativo. Mi pregunta es si existe un equivalente a este archivo en Linux (por ejemplo, "linux.h").
Muchas gracias

Comment: Si pero no. Hay cabeceras concretas de POSIX, recogidas en la especificación. Y hay cabeceras exclusivas de Linux, que estan bajo `/usr/include/linux/ ...`. Pero no es 1, son bastantes.

Comment: Existe la cabecera <unistd.h>, que está en todos los sistemas unix-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows es un sistema que en muchos aspectos es monolítico, es decir, Windows es lo que és y tienes poco margen de cambio aparte de cambios estéticos. Por poner un ejemplo, puedes elegir si los accesos directos van a tener una flechita delatora o no pero no puedes añadir nuevos protocolos de red (así, Windows 95, que no dispone de los protocolos https actuales, es incapaz de navegar por la web).

Linux, en cambio, es un sistema altamente personalizable en la que todos los componentes pueden ser reemplazados.. así, para empezar, tienes varios tipos de escritorio (Gnome, KDE, ...). Dado que cada paquete lo ha programado un grupo diferente, sus dependencias, requisitos, interfaces y funcionalidades serán diferentes, vale que tendrán que cumplir con algunas restricciones... pero para el resto del diseño ancha es castilla.

Así, mientras que en Windows es facil proveer una colección simplificada de archivos que te permitan conectar con la API del Sistema Operativo, en Linux es otro cantar... si encesitas interactuar con Gnome tendrás que ver sus interfaces para saber cómo usar sus servicios, y lo mismo si acabas dependiendo de KDE y así para todas las dependencias de las que hagas uso.

Como puedes ver, no tiene ningun sentido que Linux disponga de una cabecera tipo Linux.h, porque ... ¿qué pondrías ahí?

Comment: ¿Y alguna cabecera "gnome.h"?

Comment: Yo lo busco para la raspberry pi 3
A lo mejor hay cabecera para eso...